# Create a video file on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, video, media

In my Android app, I'm trying to create a video file, adding an audio track at a given time position on the video.
I used a MediaMuxer and changed the value of `presentationTimeUs` to shift the audio.
But apparently this is not the way to go, because the starting time of the video is also shifted.
Another problem is that mp3 audio does not work.
Here is my attempt so far:

```
final long audioPositionUs = 10000000;
File fileOut = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (
  Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/output.mp4");
fileOut.createNewFile ();
MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor ();
MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor ();
AssetFileDescriptor videoDescriptor = getAssets ().openFd ("video.mp4");
// AssetFileDescriptor audioDescriptor = getAssets ().openFd ("audio.mp3"); // ?!
AssetFileDescriptor audioDescriptor = getAssets ().openFd ("audio.aac");
videoExtractor.setDataSource (videoDescriptor.getFileDescriptor (),
    videoDescriptor.getStartOffset (), videoDescriptor.getLength ());
audioExtractor.setDataSource (audioDescriptor.getFileDescriptor (),
    audioDescriptor.getStartOffset (), audioDescriptor.getLength ());
MediaFormat videoFormat = null;
for (int i = 0; i < videoExtractor.getTrackCount (); i++) {
  if (videoExtractor.getTrackFormat (i).getString (
      MediaFormat.KEY_MIME).startsWith ("video/")) {
    videoExtractor.selectTrack (i);
    videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat (i);
    break;
  }
}
audioExtractor.selectTrack (0);
MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat (0);
MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer (fileOut.getAbsolutePath (),
    MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack (videoFormat);
int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack (audioFormat);
boolean end = false;
int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
ByteBuffer videoBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate (sampleSize);
ByteBuffer audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate (sampleSize);
MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo ();
MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo ();
videoExtractor.seekTo (0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
audioExtractor.seekTo (0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
muxer.start ();
while (!end) {
  videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData (videoBuffer, 0);
  if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0) {
    end = true;
    videoBufferInfo.size = 0;
  } else {
    videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime ();
    videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags ();
    muxer.writeSampleData (videoTrack, videoBuffer, videoBufferInfo);
    videoExtractor.advance ();
  }
}
end = false;
while (!end) {
  audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData (audioBuffer, 0);
  if (audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
    end = true;
    audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
  } else {
    audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime () +
        audioPositionUs;
    audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags ();
    muxer.writeSampleData (audioTrack, audioBuffer, audioBufferInfo);
    audioExtractor.advance ();
  }
}
muxer.stop ();
muxer.release ();
```

Can you please give details (and code if possible) to help me solve this?

Comment: Hi, In case you need an ffmeg based solution, please let me know.
With ffmeg you can easily add audio to a video file.

Answer (score 1):

Send AudioRecord's samples to a MediaCodec + MediaMuxer wrapper. Using the system time at audioRecord.read(...) works sufficiently well as an audio timestamp, provided you poll often enough to avoid filling up AudioRecord's internal buffer (to avoid drift between the time you call read and the time AudioRecord recorded the samples). Too bad AudioRecord doesn't directly communicate timestamps...

// Setup AudioRecord

```
while (isRecording) {
    audioPresentationTimeNs = System.nanoTime();
    audioRecord.read(dataBuffer, 0, samplesPerFrame);
    hwEncoder.offerAudioEncoder(dataBuffer.clone(), audioPresentationTimeNs);
}
```

Note that AudioRecord only guarantees support for 16 bit PCM samples, though MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer takes input as byte[]. Passing a byte[] to audioRecord.read(dataBuffer,...) will truncate split the 16 bit samples into 8 bit for you.

I found that polling in this way still occasionally generated a timestampUs XXX < lastTimestampUs XXX for Audio track error, so I included some logic to keep track of the bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs reported by mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutMs) and adjust if necessary before calling mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may create a temporary audio track by padding your audio track at the head with a silent track, and then use it with `addTrack`.

PS: I would have thought `presentationTimeUs` should work as well.

PS2: perhaps the `set` method of [`MediaCodec.BufferInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.BufferInfo) may help.